# Programmatically set field value after POST in Django Forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a user registration form, and I want the initial password to be the same as the social security number. For some reason, I need to keep the actual password input, so I only hid it.

Now I'm struggling with setting the value of the password before it gets validated. I was under the impression that `clean()` calls the validation stuff, so naturally I wrote this:

```
def clean(self):
    self.data['password1'] = self.data['password2'] = self.data['personal_number']
    return super(SomeForm, self).clean()
```

This is however not working, because the field apparently gets validated before I can populate it. Help?

Answer (score 0):

```
def clean_password1(self):
    return self.cleaned_data['personal_number']

def clean_password2(self):
    return self.cleaned_data['personal_number']
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. The validation appears to be happening first.